# <script> onload fires when ...?

Tags: javascript, dom

In the function below from Mozilla, JS is used to add a  tag into the document. I'm confused when the onload event fires. Does onload fire when the script starts to download or has already downloaded?

```
function prefixScript(url, onloadFunction) {
  var newScript = document.createElement("script");
  newScript.onerror = loadError;
  if (onloadFunction) { newScript.onload = onloadFunction; }
  document.currentScript.parentNode.insertBefore(newScript, document.currentScript);
  newScript.src = url;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

[`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)'s callback is called when these have been completed:

1. The HTTP request to fetch the script file has been completed successfully
2. The script content has been parsed
3. The script has been executed, thus possibly exposing new global variables and/or triggering side effects like DOM manipulation or XHR

Here's a demo where a script for jQuery library is added to `<head>`, thus exposing the global variable `$` created by the execution of the imported script:

```js
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = () => {
  try {
    $;
    console.log('onload - $ is defined');
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('onload - $ is not defined yet');
  }
}

script.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js';

try {
  $;
  console.log('main - $ is defined');
} catch(e) {
  console.log('main - $ is not defined yet');
}
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Last precision - int this case, the load is triggered by appending the script to the DOM, not by `script.src = ...`! Try commenting out the last line - the script never loads.

There can also be other cases where the load is triggered by `script.src = ...`, for example when the script is appened to the DOM, the the `.src` is set.

Comment: Note that the last part is not necessarily true. You can also first append the script to the DOM and the the loading will be triggered when you later set the `src` attribute.

Answer (score -3):

From the [MDN GlobalEventHandlers.onload docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload):

> The load event fires when a given resource **has loaded**.

There is also an event for [onloadstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onloadstart) called when loading for that resource is started.

Comment: The answer is correct but it is IMHO completely trivial that `onload` fires on load

Comment: @NinoFiliu I did also mark the question as offtopic and that it should be closed, but still wanted to help by posting an answer.

Comment: Why off topic? What has become of stack overflow...? Your answer would be more helpful if you drew the connection between GlobalEventHandlers.onload and and asset load for a script tag.

Comment: @bresson Because "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers", not a search engine. It is offtopic because the question is, as can be seen from my answer, about the documentation of a function. Googling for the title of this question "onload fires when" gives a first page full of relevant results. If SO is being spammed with questions like this, asking about documentation of specific APIs all the "professionals" and "enthusiasts" will stop wasting time acting as a google middleware and will have a hard time finding question worth answering.